# Scikit-learn randomforestclassifier error on fitting

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

So I am trying to use the random forest classifier from scikit-learn and I use tfidfvectorizer to create a feature set, then use test_train_split to create X_train and Y_train. I pass this into the fit function on a random forest classifier set up like this:

```
RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_estimators=10, max_depth=1, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
```

However I run into a pandas error after:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
```

and end up getting empty dataframe failed to iterate on column errors like so:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(column headers listed out properly here)]
Index: []
Failed to iterate on column: (a name)
Failed to iterate on column: (b name)
Failed to iterate on column: (c name)
```

I have a fairly imbalanced dataset with some columns have 50k samples and some having 100ish so is that possibly and issue when using randomforestclassifier? Is there a need for there to be x many trees less than the smallest column length so that each tree can get a subset of y size?

It should also be noted that it doesn't crash, it just finishes and prints metrics which are absolutely terrible with most columns being straight up 0 and the larger categories being maybe 40% at most.

Comment: So, you have some features with 50k records and some with around 100 records?  Drop the features that have around 100 records and re-run your process.  This is adding nothing, whatsoever, to the analysis.  What is the result after you re-run the job?